# DocuSign c# api - How can I set the envelopeId?

Tags: docusignapi

I need to be able to set the envelopeId using the c# api

```
        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();


        envDef.EmailSubject = "Test Sign";
        envDef.EmailBlurb = "Blurb Text";

        envDef.EnvelopeId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

However,

```
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

        // print the JSON response
        txtDSResults.Text = string.Format("EnvelopeSummary:\n{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelopeSummary));
```

the envelope summary clearly show that a new envelopeId has been created and the supplied envelopeId ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design DocuSign will be assigning the envelopeId. You could use a [custom field](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20Envelope%20Custom%20Fields%20to%20an%20Envelope.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____50) on the envelope to keep track of how your system is identifying the envelope. Custom fields are also searchable if that is something you need as well. If you want it to be a hidden value set the `show` property to `false`.

Comment: Hi, do you know if there are any c# examples anywhere, can't see anything in corerecipies.cs, thanks

Comment: Update: I've managed to set the custom field such that I can search for it on the DocuSign site, however, its not returned using GetEnevelope. I'm trying to look for details on EnvelopesApi.GetEnvelopeOptions but can't find anything yet..

Comment: To retrieve the custom fields of an `Envelope` call the `EnvelopesApi.ListCustomFields` and specify the envelopeId that you got back from DS when the envelope was created. It will return a [CustomFieldsEnvelope](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/main/csharp/DocuSign/eSign/Model/CustomFieldsEnvelope.cs) object with all of the custom fields included.